# aws cloud formation update packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In aws cloud formation I know you can update the stack by updating the json file and those changes will take affect but how could I just update the stacks packages for example `yum update` or `apt update` etc ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add these commands in `user data`, when create new instance in cloudformation template.

Comment: that's fine on creation but if I update the stack will it not go through all the user data and for example clone the repo again and install packages I already have. how does it know only to do certain things on an update >

Comment: you need `cfn-init` to refresh the service. now I know how to answer your question.

Comment: you able to give me an example of how to do it with initial setup and update ?

Comment: See my answer, if you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample for you on how to handle your problem.

Update the code in Cloudformation template in `userdata`.

```
 "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "yum update -y \n",

             "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
             "         --configsets InstallAndRun ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
        ]]}}
```

If you need know cfn-init, read this url [cfn-init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html)

If you need a sample template, see here: [Deploying Applications on Amazon EC2 with AWS CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html)

Comment: got a little question, so if I had a git clone in the UserData which I want to run on the inital setup won't that run when I do the updater ?